# Ansible: Efficient way of defining "vars" in multiple plays/tasks?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Ansible: Efficient way of defining "vars" in multiple plays/tasks

We have got 100's of playbooks, tasks etc. In many of the tasks, we need to extract a unique var & based on thhat set of another "vars" from a lookup. This is mainly for meta-information and append to template. But every time I have to put vars, we need to put them one by one in the task. Is there a better/efficient way to make the "vars" itself like a template? So I can just use a template and fill up all the vars?

Please find an example

```
- name: "play1, task1"
  file:
    something..
  loop: my_dict1
  vars:
    empID: {{item|someSplitting|anothercalculation}}
    empFirstName: {{empID|some_filter}}
    ... set_of_20_vars_based_on_empID_lookup

- name: "a separate play/task"
  <another_activity>:
    something..
  loop: another_dict_to_stitch_together_to_my_dict1
  vars:
    somethingDifferent: {{item|someCalculation}}
    empID: {{somethingDifferent|someSplitting|anothercalculation}}
    empFirstName: {{empID|some_filter}}
    ... set_of_20_vars_based_on_empID_lookup repeated
```

So I was looking for an option in the vars, where I can define ALL those 20+ vars into a single place, so I can just re-use it?
something like below..

```
- name: "Any task"
  template:
    <fill_my_template_with_vars>
  loop: my_any_dict_or_list
  vars:
    somethingDifferent2: {{item|someCalculation}}
    empID: {{somethingDifferent2|someSplitting|anothercalculation}}
    my_employee_vars: {{import_List_of_all_standard_20vars_lookup}}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you redefine the same vars for each task, simply define them once at play level. Bars are evaluated each time they are used, so this will work for each item in the iteration

Comment: But as you can see I've to fill a "template" based on those vars, so that has to be dynamic at a task level

Comment: Have you actually tried my suggestion ? => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/89d074788d190abc7e66868953500db9. Or did I totally miss the point ? Note that any play level var defined using `item` will fire an error if used in a task that doesn't have a loop.

Comment: Note that if you want to reuse those vars in different plays there are several possible solutions including 1) define them in `group_vars/all.yml` in your inventory 2) define them in `whatever/file.yml` and include them at play level with `vars_files:` wherever you need them.

Comment: Thanks for that. in the gist example,
```vars:
    item_length: "{{ item | length }}"
    item_double_length: "{{ item_length | int * 2 }}"
    item_prefixed: "totoprefix-{{ item }}"
```

So what you are saying is the `{{item}}` used can be dynamic, i.e. can be changed based on the task? Then thats whhat i'm actually looking for .. if you can make it as a post, I can accept it.

Comment: `Vars are evaluated each time they are used, so this will work for each item in the iteration`

Comment: thanks mate. if you can please make your gist example as an answer, I can accept it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just put the data into a dictionary:

`group_vars/all.yml`

```
employee_data:
  '1234567':
    first: Fred
    last: Flintstone
    start_date: "8-OCT-29,118BC"
    filing_status: married
    dependents: 2
  '1847882':
    first: Barney
    last: Rubble
    start_date: "12-JUN-29,110BC"
    filing_status: married
    dependents: 2
```

Then `show_emp_data.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: Client1
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    emp_data: "{{ employee_data[emp_id] }}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: employee_data
  - debug:
      var: emp_data
```

Now we run `ansible-playbook show_emp_data.yml -e emp_id=1847882`

```
PLAY [Client1] *************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [Client1] => {
    "employee_data": {
        "1234567": {
            "dependents": 2,
            "filing_status": "married",
            "first": "Fred",
            "last": "Flintstone",
            "start_date": "8-OCT-29,118BC"
        },
        "1847882": {
            "dependents": 2,
            "filing_status": "married",
            "first": "Barney",
            "last": "Rubble",
            "start_date": "12-JUN-29,110BC"
        }
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [Client1] => {
    "emp_data": {
        "dependents": 2,
        "filing_status": "married",
        "first": "Barney",
        "last": "Rubble",
        "start_date": "12-JUN-29,110BC"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
Client1                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I don't have flexiblity to run another play as each task is within control of their own individual team. But as per your post, is there a way to pass the "empID" to another task and get back teh values?

 I need the vars individually to be used to fill up jinja template at each "task" level (per loop)

Comment: I don't quite understand.  What DO you have control of?  The jinja template?  Just the template task?